# PL/SQL update blob column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table in Oracle with a blob field and want to UPDATE image in it using some query. I know it can be done by uploading image using interface, but is there some way to update the image using query?

Table1

```
Id;Image;FileName;FilePath
```

The image is stored in the `Image` column.

Comment: Where is the image currently stored?

Comment: Where is the NEW image stored?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBMS_LOB` package, especially its `LOADFROMFILE` procedure.

See http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_lob.html, search for "Blob Load Demo".